# Django Test RequestFactory post with foreign key

Tags: django, requestfactory

I'm trying to test a view-function with django's `RequestFactory`'s  post-method. The view-function should create a new `ObjA`-instance. `ObjA` has a foreign key field to an `ObjB`.

My test currently looks like this (names changed for better reading):

```
request = self.factory.post('/create-objA/', data={'objB': objB.id, 'field1': 'dummy'})
request.user = self.user
request.POST.is_bound = True
create_objA(request)
self.assertTrue(ObjA.objects.filter(field1='dummy').exists())
```

`objB` does exist, this is tested few lines before in the same test function.

However the test in the snippet fails. The reason is that in the following create function `form.is_valid()` is never `true`:

```
def create_objA(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ObjAFormCreate(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            ....
```

So the `ObjA` is not created. Form is not valid because it has an error in the `ObjB` reference field:

```
Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.
```

though `objB.id` is inside `form.data`.

**Question:** How should I write the test, so that the `form` would not have the error?

Model:

```
class ObjA(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    obj_b_id = models.ForeignKey(ObjB, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Form:

```
class ObjAFormCreate(ModelForm):
    objB = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ObjB.objects.all())
    field1 = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. It looks like the code is correct and there is a bug either in Django or in my IDE, because after some changes and tries it started to work with exactly the same code. I don't know why the behaviour is not deterministic at some points.